# Finding parameters at point of intersection of 2 lines using triple products

Tags: vectors

I have 2 equations of lines:
$\mathbf{r}_1(s) = \mathbf{a} + s\mathbf{m}$ and 
$\mathbf{r}_2(t) = \mathbf{b} + t\mathbf{n}$
and I need to find the values of **s** and **t** at the point of intersection of the two lines, in terms of the scalar triple products of **a**, **b**, **m** and **n**, where [**a**, **m**, **n**] is not zero.

I managed to prove that a necessary condition for 2 lines to intersect is when [**a**-**b**,**m**,**n**] is not zero. How do I proceed from there?

Comment: $|[a+sm-b\times n]|=0$ and $|[b+tn-a\times m]|=0$, and use $[a\times b]\cdot [c\times d]=\dots$

Comment: Can you please explain a little what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\b}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$
I'll denote $[\b{x}\times \b{y}]$ or $[\b{x}, \b{y}]$ the cross product; $(\b{x}, \b{y})$ or $\b{x}\cdot \b{y}$ the dot product; and $(\b{x},\b{y},\b{z})=[\b{x}\times\b{y}]\cdot\b{z}$ the mixed product.
Let $\b{a}+s\b{m}=\b{b}+t\b{n}$ the intersection point. Then $\b{a}-\b{b}+s\b{m}=t\b{n}$, so $(\b{a}-\b{b}+s\b{m})||\b{n}$ unless $t=0$, so 
$[(\b{a}-\b{b}+s\b{m})\times\b{n}]=\b{0}$. Analogically $[(\b{b}-\b{a}+t\b{n})\times\b{m}]=\b{0}$.
Then we re-write 
$\begin{cases}[(\b{b}-\b{a}+t\b{n})\times\b{m}]=\b{0}\\
[(\b{a}-\b{b}+s\b{m})\times\b{n}]=\b{0}
\end{cases}$ as 
$\begin{cases}[\b{b}-\b{a}\times\b{m}]+t[\b{n}\times\b{m}]=\b{0}\\
[\b{a}-\b{b}\times\b{n}]+s[\b{m}\times\b{n}]=\b{0}
\end{cases}$.
Then we take scalar squares of both equalities to obtain pure scalar conditions on $s,\,t$ and use formula 
$$[\b{x}\times\b{y}]\cdot[\b{p}\times\b{q}]=
(\b{x},\b{p})(\b{y},\b{q})-(\b{x},\b{q})(\b{y},\b{p})\hbox{.}$$